# Using subplots columns in pandas hvplot with groupby

Tags: python, pandas, hvplot

I am trying to create 2x2 subplots with hvplot.pandas widget groupby.
Without the groupby it is working with no issues:

```
import pandas as pd
import hvplot.pandas
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[0 ,1, 2, 3], 'a': [1, 2, 8, 5], 'b': [200, 300, 50 ,0], 'c': [-1, -5, 5, 3], 'd': [0, 0, 1 , 2], 'group': [1, 1, 2, 2]})
df.hvplot(x='x', y=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], width=300, height=300, subplots=True, shared_axes=False).cols(2)
```

[image]

But if I'm trying to use the `groupby` option it will fail

```
df.hvplot(x='x', y=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], width=300, height=300, subplots=True, groupby='group', shared_axes=False).cols(2)
```

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
> ~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_26852\2636154207.py in 
> ----> 1 df.hvplot(x='x', y=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], width=300, height=300, subplots=True, groupby='group', shared_axes=False).cols(2)

AttributeError: 'DynamicMap' object has no attribute 'cols'

Is there any elegant workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Just put by='group' instead of groupby ='group'

import pandas as pd
import hvplot.pandas

df.hvplot(x='x', y=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], width=300, height=300, subplots=True, shared_axes=False, by='group').cols(2)

Comment: I want to get the widget to select a group